# Sequelize complex join statement

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I recently switched from the C# stack to full stack javascript and decided to use Sequelize for my project. I want to write a query where i get the user and the related Role and Tenant objects. I used the official docs as a guidance but somehow I am missing something.

docs that I use as reference:
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/querying.html#relations---associations

Database model:
[image]

Code to retrieve the user:

```
let user = await User.findOne({
            where: { email },
            [
                include: {
                    model: Tenant,
                    where: { id: Sequelize.col('user.tenantId') }
                },
                include: {
                    model: Role,
                    where: { id: Sequelize.col('user.roleId') }
                },

            ]
        });
```

any help is much appreciated, Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have defined the association in sequlize, then there no need of condition within include, and there might be syntax issue with how you include the models , please review the below query :

```
User.findOne({
    where: { email },
    include: [
        {
            model: Tenant,
            // where: { id: Sequelize.col('user.tenantId') }  // <--- REMOVE
        },
        {
            model: Role,
            // where: { id: Sequelize.col('user.roleId') }  // <--- REMOVE
        }
    ]
});
```